# Redirect the default page to home.html in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, cpanel

I'm trying to have the `example.com` redirected to `example.com/home.html`

I have `.htaccess` file in cPanel public HTML folder but it doesn't work

I'm new to this so apologies if it's completely wrong

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9_/]{0,6}$ home.html [R=301,NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

you just add this code in the last line in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/home\.html" [R=301,L]
```

or

```
Redirect 301 http://example.com http://example.com/home.html
```

Comment: Your RewriteRule looks fine, but your `Redirect 301` directive won't do what you want.   That directive takes a path starting with `/` for the "old URL" argument, so `/` rather than `http://example.com`.  But then it is also recursive.  It will redirect all sub-directories and files within the root directory as well. You'll end up with a redirect to `home.html`, but then it will recursively redirect back to itself. [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)

Comment: `RedirectMatch ^/$ http://example.com/home.html` would work as long as it doesn't conflict with any rewrite rules.

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practice to redirect the base URL. Instead you should just rename `home.html` to `index.html`. Then it will power `http://example.com/` with no rules needed.

Another possibility is to use

```
DirectoryIndex home.html
```

in your `.htaccess` which will change the name of the default page. Here is the documentation about what your default file should be named and how to change it if desired: [mod_dir - DirectoryIndex Apache HTTP Server Version 2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex)

You should also change links to your home page from `<a href=home.html>` to `<a href=/>`.  Then users and search engines will never know the actual file name that powers your home page.